# Can't use class members from class in header file (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, include

I have

```
//a.h file

class A {
public:
   int var_A;
};
```

and

```
//b.h file
#include "a.h"

class B {
public:
   A* A_pntr;
   void fooB() {
      A* other_A_pntr = A_pntr;      //this works
      std::cout << A_pntr->var_A;    //this fails
   }
};
```

I can only use class `A` in a pointer,
but can't use specific variables or functions.

I did the same thing in other files of my project and it works. It only fails in one file and there is nothing different in the code.

Precompiled headers are also turned off.

It's as if `A` was only forward declared.

Error message: `C2027: Usage of undeclared type "A"`

Any help is appreciated!

Note: To give more clarification about my project:

I have a base class defined in one header file and derived classes in their own header files. Most of them use the other derived classes, meaning I include the proper header file and have a reference to that class inside the other class (so I can use the members). It works everywhere except here and all derived classes are practically the same. The only solution I found online was "precompiled headers". But I have that turned off already.

Comment: `A->var_A;` --> `other_A_pntr->var_A;`, or `A_pntr->var_A;`. Even that's going to be an error since `var_A` is private.

Comment: @cigien My bad, I went too far with "minimal code example" and forgot about that part.

Comment: Is the missing semicolon at the end of the `A` definition in `a.h` in the original or a transcription error?

Comment: @NathanPierson It does have a closing bracket in both

Comment: @JaMiT My fault, of course it was supposed to be ```A_pntr->var_A```

Comment: I know it has a closing bracket, I'm asking about the semicolon `;` that goes after the closing bracket.

Comment: @NathanPierson I added the semicolon since it seems to cause a different error message (and not cause the stated error message). Although if that punctuation was not in the original code, AnonPJ please remove it again.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm too used to code editors :)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that reproduces your error

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sadly the error does not reproduce itself. As mentioned, I have other classes and header files in my project that do the exact same thing and work perfectly fine. And when I started a new VS solution and tried the same concept, it also worked fine. At this point I suppose it's in the VS settings.  Eitherway, I already found a work-around, tho I still don't know what went wrong so I can't answer the question myself sadly